# States for derivatives of wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differentiation

Given a wave function $\psi_t(x)$. The quantum state of a system at time t can be written as the sum of basis states multiplied by the amplitude:

$$|t\rangle = \int \psi_t(x)|x\rangle dx^3$$

What states do the partial derivates represent (if anything?):

$$|t,\mu\rangle = \int \frac{\partial \psi_t(x)}{\partial x_\mu}|x\rangle dx^3$$

Or for that matter does this have a meaning?:

$$|t\rangle' = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|t\rangle = \int \dot{\psi}_t(x)|x\rangle dx^3$$ 
Well in this case I would think $|t\rangle'$ would represent the small difference between a state at time $t$ and it's predecessor.

Comment: Wavefunctions need not be differentiable.

Comment: Yes, but it is in this case. Am I to presume it has no known meaning?

Comment: Also, if the wavefunction satisfied the Shrodinger equation, it would have to be differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an interpretative question of the bra-ket formalism. In more mainstream notation, $\langle x |\psi_t\rangle =\psi_t(x) $,
$$
|\psi_t\rangle= \int\!\! d^3x ~ |x\rangle \psi_t(x) ,   
$$
so that 
$$
  \int\!\! d^3x ~ |x\rangle \partial_\mu \psi_t(x) =  
  \int\!\! d^3x ~ |x\rangle \partial_\mu \langle x|\psi_t\rangle =\frac{i}{\hbar } \hat p_\mu  |\psi_t\rangle ,
$$
which is to say an infinitesimal translation on the state. You may, of course, exponentiate for finite translations. For instance, in one dimension, $\langle x| e^{ia\hat p /\hbar} |\psi_t\rangle = \psi_t(x+a)$.

Likewise,
$$
  \int\!\! d^3x ~ |x\rangle \partial_t \psi_t(x) =  
  \int\!\! d^3x ~ |x\rangle   \langle x|\dot {\psi}_t\rangle = \dot{  |\psi}_t\rangle = \frac{-i}{\hbar} H |\psi_t\rangle,
$$
since *t* is a parameter of the state, and has no peculiar Hilbert space features.

Comment: What does a translated state mean exactly? Is it just a change of origin? So basically, the translated states, are just a different representation?

Comment: It has exactly 187.35 meanings. It is a translation of a state. Might use in a broad variety of contexts, like a dumpster fire of synecdoches. It would be a poor representation for several technical reasons.